# Get number in between two numbers JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

How can I get the `number` in *between* two numbers?

So for example:

```
var start = 0;
var end = 100;
var inBetween = 50;
```

In my case it will be something like:

```
var start = -122.0842499;
var end = 5.6366264;
var inBetween = "How do I get the exact number in between start and end?";
```

I tried following, but it returns an incorrect number.

```js
var start = -122.0842499;
var end = 5.6366264;
var inBetween = start + end / 2;

console.log(inBetween) // Outputs -119.2659367
```

Comment: `(a + b) / 2` ?

Comment: value 1 + value 2 devided by 2 ( just maths)

Comment: Ok, lets try that.

Comment: My math sucks :|

Comment: @Red well look at the answer

Comment: Do you need random value between start and end?

Comment: No, the *exact number*.

Comment: In this case Federico gave valid answer but (a + b)/2 simpler.

Comment: This looks like latitude and longitude

Comment: @emil well seen, It are indeed longitude value's ;)

Comment: Could people please explain the downvotes? I suck at math, and googled all over. But didnt find an awnser.

Comment: Answered to your question @Red

Comment: @emil yes, I see. Lets see what it outputs when I apply that to my script.

Comment: You should update your question if you are looking for center between 2 coordinates.

Comment: @AndrewNepogoda Its not relevant, because I just need the number in between.

Comment: Don't think too much about downvotes on questions, these are mostly opinionated. You being bad at math(or just thinking too complicated) doesn't improve the value of the question to others. I'm more worried about the downvotes on technically correct answers and the (for random viewers) offtopicness of latlng. I think that should be a new question(or just a link to a related question).

Comment: first link from google: https://sciencing.com/calculate-midpoint-between-two-numbers-2807.html

Comment: I was searching to complicated `Get number in between JavaScript`

Comment: What @Tushar suggested, I tried somewhat similair. But I didnt know about the `()`. Thats why it returned the incorrect number and I was getting stuck. So I added that to the question, so it will be more clear what my issue was. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the means of the two numbers, that is

```
var start = -122.0842499;
var end = 5.6366264;
var inBetween = (start + end) / 2;
```

Having said that, if you're really working with coordinates, the correct way to do this is @emil's answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is it. It looks so easy if I look at your awnser. to me math is like chinese. I suck at it.

Comment: Hm, someone downvoted. Could you please explain why this awnser isn't correct? To me it looks correct.

Comment: @Red I don't know the downvoter's reason, but this answer is unnecessary complicated: `end - ((end - start) /2)` is exactly the same of `(start + end)/2`, which is a very basic math. Let's see: `end - ((end - start) /2)` = `(2 * end - end + start)/2` = `(end + start)/2`.

Comment: Yes, I just found out. @Federico could you explain why you use `end - ((end - start) /2)` instead of `(a + b) / 2`. Just curious if it has any befenit over `(a + b) / 2`

Comment: I'm wondering about the complicatedness too, unless you're expecting some issue with very large (positive) numbers?

Comment: It was just the first thing that popped into my head, no reason in particular. But I reckon it's overly complicated.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca in that case, why don't you edit your answer?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca and now it's worse. Your answer gives the idea that the two things are different, when they are *exactly the same*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yep, my wording sucked. Edited again.

Comment: Now it's better.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I'm on an editing spree. Now it's even better I think.

Answer (score 3):

As it is longitude and latitude, `(a+b)/2` is not correct. Earth is not flat.

```
//-- Define radius function
if (typeof (Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined") {
    Number.prototype.toRad = function () {
        return this * Math.PI / 180;
    }
}

//-- Define degrees function
if (typeof (Number.prototype.toDeg) === "undefined") {
    Number.prototype.toDeg = function () {
        return this * (180 / Math.PI);
    }
}


function middlePoint(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {

    //-- Longitude difference
    var dLng = (lng2 - lng1).toRad();

    //-- Convert to radians
    lat1 = lat1.toRad();
    lat2 = lat2.toRad();
    lng1 = lng1.toRad();

    var bX = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLng);
    var bY = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLng);
    var lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + bX) * (Math.cos(lat1) + bX) + bY * bY));
    var lng3 = lng1 + Math.atan2(bY, Math.cos(lat1) + bX);

    //-- Return result
    return [lng3.toDeg(), lat3.toDeg()];
}
```

Taken from http://jsfiddle.net/kevinrignault/gzq64p56/

Comment: Thanks for the awnser. But as it doesn't really matter if it are coördinates, I accept the simplest awnser. I just need the number in between the given values. Regardless coördinates or not. I upvote for your effort though.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var start = -122.0842499;
var end = 5.6366264;
var inBetween = (start+end)/2
console.log(inBetween)
```